# Is there or will there be a way to request payment?

Tags: plutus, ada, yoroi

Is there any development going on with this? Or do I lack the understanding of how this works. I'm thinking something similar to Zelle or Venmo. Sorry if this has already been asked or is not possible, I'm brand new and trying to be involved.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Cardano stack exchange. Currently it is not possible to request a payment from someone else using the official Yoroi or Daedalus wallets. I'm also unaware of any developments in this direction. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Requesting payments is a third-party affair for the most part. In the world of “Don’t call us, we’ll call you”, it’s the other way round crypto/blockchain tech.  Every activity/transaction for the most part is executed by the user. Exceptions are contract-contract interactions.

In conclusion; third-party apps can be built to send notifications that request payments but that’s not a core aspect to blockchain tech AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment. In Yoroi you can generate a link that you can send to someone else. The other person must use Yoroi too to open the link. The link contains your address and the amount of ADA you request from the other person.

So it would be possible to create some sort of service that transmits this link to someone else. For now you have to manually send the link to someone else.